# can confluent-python produce data with value in avro and key in string?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm using python3 and [confluent-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) to send a message to Kafka. I need to send data with value in Avro format and the key as a string. But I found the confluent-python can only send both in Avro or both in the string. The confluent-python source code is as blew:

```
def produce(self, **kwargs):
    """
        Asynchronously sends a message to Kafka by encoding with specified or default Avro schema.

        :param str topic: topic name
        :param object value: An object to serialize
        :param str value_schema: Avro schema for value
        :param object key: An object to serialize
        :param str key_schema: Avro schema for key

        Plus any other parameters accepted by confluent_kafka.Producer.produce

        :raises SerializerError: On serialization failure
        :raises BufferError: If producer queue is full.
        :raises KafkaException: For other produce failures.
    """
    # get schemas from  kwargs if defined
    key_schema = kwargs.pop('key_schema', self._key_schema)
    value_schema = kwargs.pop('value_schema', self._value_schema)
    topic = kwargs.pop('topic', None)
    if not topic:
        raise ClientError("Topic name not specified.")
    value = kwargs.pop('value', None)
    key = kwargs.pop('key', None)

    if value is not None:
        if value_schema:
            value = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, value_schema, value)
        else:
            raise ValueSerializerError("Avro schema required for values")

    if key is not None:
        if key_schema:
            key = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, key_schema, key, True)
        else:
            raise KeySerializerError("Avro schema required for key")

    super(AvroProducer, self).produce(topic, value, key, **kwargs)
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: Currently have the same issue - trying to produce data with a schema for the value but no schema for the key (just need it to be a string). Did you find a workaround/solution?

Comment: Not yet, I looked into the source code and I suppose it does not support this feature. In kafka, the key decides  which partition will the message go to, so deserialize the key is not that important.

Comment: Issue for this here:  https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/428

Answer (score 2):

Define a PrimitiveSchema - string like this:

`key_schema = avro.loads('{"type": "string"}')`

and use it like this when you construct your producer:

`producer = avro.AvroProducer(config=conf, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=your_value_schema)`

Comment: Alternatively, use `from avro import schema` and `key_schema = schema.parse('{"type": "string"}')` to define the key_schema.

Answer (score 1):

So my workaround was just to change the Python code to not raise the exception. I'm assuming the authors of the library don't allow the flexibility of using a schema only for key or only for value for a reason, but don't know what it is. For my use case of needing to publish this kind of data in development I thought this was an OK fix.

Code change is in `confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py` and is simply removing lines 87 and 88:

```
84    if key is not None:
85        if key_schema:
86            key = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, key_schema, key, True)
87        else:
88            raise KeySerializerError("Avro schema required for key")
```

Comment: Indeed, looking at Producer.produce (AvroProducer's super), the key may be a "str" or "bytes".

Comment: However, see my answer-- you don't have to change the library code to serialize a key as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider:

- handling [de]serialization manually,
- using https://github.com/saabeilin/kafkian (that uses confluent-kafka-python under the hood)